# how to redraw a div using jquery (webflow custom code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, slider, webflow

I'm trying to create a modal activated by jquery. Inside that modal I have a slider created in webflow, but this slider isn't working.
The webflow support suggests to insert, after the modal activator, this line of code: `Webflow.require('slider').redraw();`

But it's not working.

Here's my code:

```js
$('#plus-1').on('click', function() {

    //apri la modal corrispondente
    $("#modal-1").css('display', 'flex');
    //$('.slider').redraw();
    Webflow.require('slider').redraw();

     $('#chiudi-1').on('click', function() {
    //chiudi la modal corrispondente
    $("#modal-1").css('display', 'none');
});});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/princype-2/js/configurator-princype-rev002.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/princype-2/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/princype-2/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/princype-2/css/configurator-princype-rev002.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  
  
<button id="plus-1" type="button">Click Me!</button>
  

<div id="modal-1" class="modal-prezzi porta-h240 logged">
    <div class="info-wrapper-checkout logged">
    <a id="chiudi-1" class="chiudi checkout logged">x</a>
      <div id="slider-1" class="slider w-slider">
        <div class="w-slider-mask">
          <div class="img_int-pack-premium-plus a w-slide">
          </div>
          <div class="img_int-pack-premium-plus b w-slide">
          </div>
          <div class="img_int-pack-premium-plus c w-slide">
          </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="w-slider-arrow-left">
          <div class="icon-2 w-icon-slider-left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-slider-arrow-right">
          <div class="icon-3 w-icon-slider-right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-nav w-slider-nav w-round"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you specifiy what "the slider does not work" means ? Is it rendered but not functional ? Is it not present in your modal at all ? What kind of modal do you use ? Bootstrap ? Is your modal content loaded at runtime or is it rendered on pageload ? The best thing would be if you provided a minimal example as a snippet that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Hi, sorry i will provide more specs.

Comment: hi @Lapskaus I have updated the question

Comment: You immediatly get some errors in your console when you run your code. After you click the button you get "Webflow is not defined". Are you sure you loaded all necessary libraries ?

Comment: I got the same error in the production file. I searched for something not defined but still doesn't work.
I have tried to change the `webflow.redaw()` with this --> `$('.slider').redraw();` but still nothing.

Comment: How do you initialize the slider ?

Comment: Hi, just found the mistake I've mised this script --> `$.fn.redraw = function(){
  $(this).each(function(){
    var redraw = this.offsetHeight;
  });
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the missing point.
before the `Webflow.require('slider').redraw();` I had to put this:

```
$.fn.redraw = function(){
  $(this).each(function(){
    var redraw = this.offsetHeight;
  });
};
```